# How to read pdf in my android application?

Tags: android, pdf-reader

I am making an application which require to open pdf.

I also have some pdf in asset folder so i am not able to open it in webview directly.

By default android does not support pdf.

Is there any API that works on android(except MuPdf) ??

My device does not have any pdf reader installed so ACTION VIEW is not helpful for me

Following is not working.......

[How to render a PDF file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)

[Open asset file pdf in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743807/open-asset-file-pdf-in-application)

Can you suggest me any good api?

Comment: [Just try this one](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)

Comment: thanks i have already  tried this... not works for me

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2916712/985143 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/6249435/985143

Comment: Thnx @ZazGmy  but i want to read pdf form my own app. because my device does not have installed any other pdf reader

Comment: Look at this Libary:
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library. Its a simple PDF Reader, this should work.

Comment: What about PDFBox? It's a java library for PDF interaction. Not sure you can use in Android.

Comment: Why not install a free pdf-reader, code the app to call it via intent, and give an error message ('please install pdf reader') if it fails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder

Answer (score 62):

I've simply done that using [PdfViewer.jar](http://www.ziddu.com/download/19248664/PdfViewer.jar.html) (download it with the blue button) and making a code like below.

**First.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {  
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
            {  
                    return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
            }  
    }); 
    pdflist = new String[imagelist.length]; 
    for(int i = 0;i<imagelist.length;i++)
    {
            pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
    }
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String path = imagelist[(int)id].getAbsolutePath();
        openPdfIntent(path);
}

private void openPdfIntent(String path) 
{
    try
    {
      final Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
      intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Second.java**

```
public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.left_arrow;
}

public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.right_arrow;
}

public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_in;
}

public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_out;
}

public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
}

public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    return R.id.etPassword;
}

public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    return R.id.btOK;
}

public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    return R.id.btExit;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    return R.id.pagenum_edit;
}
}
```

Hope this helps you lot. Try this. Don't forgot to add your `Second.java` in your manifest. Add some drawables whatever it requires in `second.java` with your drawables. And, Refer the example from [GitHub](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

Comment: Thanks @SpK my file is in asset folder and i want to read it from asset
--- file:///android_asset/test.pdf....
i have tried this.......
openPdfIntent("file:///android_asset/test.pdf");
......logcat....
ST='file 'file:///android_asset/test.pdf' not found'

Comment: +1 but its also very slow and displays JUNK characters....

Comment: @spk hello sir I am using the solution you mentioned but getting this error  E/AndroidRuntime(23933): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pdf.view.Second can you please help me

Comment: @Nitin Click your project -> right click -> properties -> Java build path -> Order and export tab -> here the library should be first and should checked.

Comment: Hi Praveen I have tried this, but is not working efficiently. Almost 80 precent time it fails to load the file. Can you suggest any other good library?

Comment: I tried this but it just keep on loading or show nothing. Any idea what's wrong...???

Comment: @KhawarRaza i guess there's a problem on your file location

Comment: For Zoom out problem please reffer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259131/adjust-the-screen-in-pdfviewer/16354094#16354094

Comment: I cannot get this jar file to work properly. I have imported and added it to the path. But when i try to make a first and second class, eclipse cannot find the reference to PdfViewerActivity?

Comment: @JohnBaum Try with Github link. And, restart your eclipse then try it out!

Comment: It is working but problem with images in pdf and yes processing slow.. still 1 vote up

Comment: @MohdMufiz See, its just sample. You have to implement it with your requirements and speed enhancement is with your hands :)

Comment: @Praveen when I am trying this sample I got java.nio.BufferUnderflowException why is it so?could you help me

Comment: what is imagelist and pdflist in this code ?

Comment: @Praveen I appreciate your work but still not getting significant answer as it is taking time in loading Pdf page. One more thing I have put PDF file in assets folder. I have to view pdf file from Asset folder. Any solution?

Comment: Me too tried this but it just keep on loading or showing nothing.

Comment: After I changing file path can able to read it but How can I get text from that PDF?

Comment: **Please Help me to solve this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045927/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-using-pdfviewer-in-android**

Comment: Hi @Praveen , I used the same library, but I'm having problem when my pdf file has scanned images. It displays broken pixelated images. Is there a solution on this? or is there any modification i need to do? thank you

Comment: Hello @KairiSan This is a simple & basic library which will just show the PDF files. You may have to implement this library as per your needs or you have to go for any other library.

Comment: thank you @Praveen for answering. I used other library instead.

Answer (score 9):

Some phones (like the Nexus One) come with a version of Quickoffice pre-installed so it may be as easy as sending the appropriate Intent once you've saved the file to the SD card.

```
public class OpenPdf extends Activity { 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton); 
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf"); 

                if (file.exists()) { 
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file); 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf"); 
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 

                    try { 
                        startActivity(intent); 
                    }  
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
                        Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this,  
                            "No Application Available to View PDF",  
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: is not this out of scope topic ?

Answer (score 1):

I have never needed to do this, but you could probably use a library like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/download.php) to access the PDF file programmatically, and then display the PDF.

Comment: is iText supports Android ????

Comment: Yes, the JAVA version can be included in an android project.

Comment: but it's not free

Comment: Don't use iText unless you are ready to pay higher charges for license