# How to read a pdf file using other App from internal memory?

Tags: java, android, pdf

In my app I am creating a pdf file in internal app files(data/data/package/files) I want these files to be readable when I read them using this code:

```
 Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
 Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
 pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I have read about using openOutputStream() method but I have no clue how to read them through this.Could anyone help me?

**EDIT**

pdfFile--

```
    File    directory=getFilesDir();
    pdfFile=new File(directory,filename+".pdf");
```

Comment: have same problam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application

Comment: what does your `pdfFile` string contain?

Comment: @Pallavi -  File    directory=getFilesDir();
       pdfFile=new File(directory,filename+".pdf");

Comment: `what does your pdfFile string contain?`  meaning the value, when you write it in LogCat or some where... `pdfFile=/mnt/data/...` what is the value of the pdfFile variable?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` to `openOutputStream()` when writing the PDF to your internal storage. In theory, that will allow third party apps to read it.

Or, implement a `ContentProvider` for this file, such as the one I demonstrate in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) (here, copying a PDF from `assets/` into internal storage).

Answer (score 0):

Add this:
pdfFile.setReadable(true, false);