# Pdf in android without other applications

Tags: android

I want to show pdf file in android, but this must work without Internet connection and other appliacation. Can I show pdf file in webView or other view?

Comment: Try below post on pdf viewer discussion :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728920/pdf-viewer-api-library-for-android-app-sample-code

Welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can show your `PDF` to your custom view. For, this you've to use one **External Jar** file for that. I've already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352422/940096) like similar to your question. Just check it out.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Using another app to display your PDFs is a really nice way to do it. Unless you have superiors forcing you to avoid other apps, I'd do it that way. There are good, free pdf viewing apps available so it won't cost your users anything.

The transition when opening a pdf in another app is pretty seamless and it's not always obvious that another app is being used.

The alternative, as SpK said, is to use a jar and write the extra pdf viewing functionality that you need. This is a much harder way to do it.