# Android - Best way to display a PDF file

Tags: android, pdf, view

I have a 600 page PDF that I call an intent from a previously installed PDF application to view. The app works fine but I have received complaints that it is just a PDF. I would like to know is there an optimal way to display a file such as this (two columns with images) in a way that it is viewed by the user in the best (mobile?) format possible?  Hopefully an automated tool, converting to word and manually changing it is a daunting task.

As I said above the app already has the ability to view the PDF file. I wanted to know what the best mobile friendly format was.

Comment: Calling Intent is the better option..if use Adobe Reader application in that settings u ve option for two columns...if v use our own code to display PDF file it is very difficult to do...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10647418/940096) can be helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below code -

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try
{
    startActivity(pdfIntent);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
{

}
```

Comment: before this u need to install pdf reader

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open PDF  you we should install PDF viewer or you can prefer NDK for reading data from PDF file.

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(path); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: generally we can't view PDF files in the emulator .