# Pdf library for android?

Tags: android, pdf-reader

I am developing a small application in which i have to show pdf file of newspaper exatly same as it is shown into the below link.This is a link press Reader app this also shows the newspaper.I had search a lot from the internet but cannot found any good library of pdfReader.
Can anybody help me how the PRESS READER(below Link) show his newspaper(pdf) in a view or if the same can be get by any other method then plz discuss.
Thanks in advance..

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newspaperdirect.pressreader.android&feature=search_result

Comment: Try my [Existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10352422/940096)

Comment: Yes i had go through the asnwer which u suggested me But the output is not as i require did you see the PRESS READER App.I want that type of functionality..

Comment: Yes, i've seen that app. After posting comment only. For this case. You've to customize the PDF pages with some libraries. Or you've to buy some SDK.

Comment: You mean Pdftron or any other paid library.

Comment: Yes. You can do with that. And, also you can ask them to how to do your requirements.

Comment: @Amandeepsingh: did you find any answer for the above issue? I am also facing problem with same thing... If you have found any thing please update it.

Comment: @Krishna I can't get any solution for this.I think you have to buy an library for this because free library is not as upto our requirement.I think the other option is Mupdf try this.I also stuck in the last few steps while implementing Mupdf Lib.

Comment: @Amandeepsingh hello,did you find any solution. I also want to read pdf in application. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Its simple...
 You can do it by using just Intent function. do following process,

1.Use GRIDVIEW for showing images as shown in the screen shots which you mentioned in the URL.
  2.on GridItemSelected Listener,just call the intent function for reading appropriate pdf..

or,if you don't want use Intent functions means,just go for itext library to read pdf