# Android PDF Viewer Library without GPL license

Tags: android, pdf

I'm looking for a PDF Viewer Library for Android without GPL License, does anybody have an idea if there's any available free-license library for that one?

Because I've been roaming around, and found some open source libraries such as MuPDF, Android PDF Viewer, DroidReader are using GPL License, which I cannot use for a commercial App I'm about to develop.

And no, I also don't want to use the google docs option ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10299839/1289716

Comment: Which one have curl/flip effect?!

Comment: I do not find this question off topic.  If only questions about pure source code were allowed, with no external libraries being used, we would be still at programming stone age.

Comment: PSPDFKit for Android is a commercial, complete PDF solution for Android. Comes with a ready-to-use Activity or Fragment and is compatible with almost all devices. https://pspdfkit.com/pdf-sdk/android/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/index.html this is a complete PDF toolkit (commercial)

Comment: any tip for a free license one where I don't need to publish my code?

Answer (score 6):

MuPDF is GPL-ed, yes.

Using GPL-ed thirdparty components in your software doesn't prohibit its commercial usage (it just requires you release the source code of your software). So... your problem isn't the GPL per se, it's that you aren't willing to release your source code, right?

But... [Artifex](http://artifex.com/) (the company behind MuPDF, Ghostscript, GhostXPS and GhostPCL) is willing to give you a **license for MuPDF** (as well as for its other products) **for commercial use**, which then doesn't require source code publishing of your stuff.

Comment: How can MuPDF be GPL'd, yet the company can offer a non-GPL'd version for commercial use?

Comment: Artifex is not the only company which *[dual-licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing)* its software....

Comment: You're quite right, companies do it -- it's a recognized business model. It just seems paradoxical to me, and counter to the intent of the GPL. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I guess the key point I was missing is that since Artifex is the copyright holder, they're not themselves bound by the terms of the GPL. So they're free to offer a non-GPL version as well. By contrast, a downstream GPL-licensee of MuPDF could not offer a dual license.

Comment: Unfortunately they are insanely expensive, you can buy a good brand new BMW for the price of a license.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy a commercial license for MuPDF.

Contact sales@artifex.com, according to their web page (I am not affiliated with them in any way). Since DroidReader uses their libs I guess their reader is pretty decent.

Comment: any tip for a free license one where I don't need to publish my code?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a good solution to our company needs (we adopted [Radaee PDF](http://www.androidpdf.mobi)) we started our evaluation and scouting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android/4766335#4766335): I think is one of the most complete here around.

Comment: I don't get it! Should i buy license or it's free?!

Comment: @Ant Picci.
Hello mate have you worked with Radaee PDF. So, did you paid for the license or is it for free. If you haven't paid, how did you resolve the issue of his name appearing on each page ?

Comment: To remove Radaee PDF watermark You must register Your library and pass credentials in Radaee library in `Global.java`. We are using paid version in standard plan.