# Open pdf file on any android device

Tags: android, pdf

I am developing an app that downloads `PDF` files from the internet and opens them. I observed that if I have an app that is capable of opening `PDF`s, it works fine (I send an intent to the OS with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`). On the emulator for example, I have no such app installed. **But** I want to show the user that `PDF` somehow, on any device. I need a general solution that works on any Android device, preferably without any external apps. Is it possible?

Comment: [Then try to integrate with this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10352422/940096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create one simple PDFViewr application and you can load your downloaded pdf into that app. I've similarly [answered to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352422/940096)

[Have a look at here also.](http://code.google.com/p/apv/) Don't forget to import the required library for this PDF application.

Hope this helps you.