# What OSes do have native support for viewing PDFs

Tags: android, windows, linux

MacOS X has PDFKit which in turn has PDFView. What other operating systems support viewing PDF files natively?

Comment: I don't see how (dis)playing a specific media format is key functionality of an OS such that it needs to be supported natively by the OS core and not by a separate application or library.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have a built-in PDF presenter. However, I found a workaround. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575099/open-pdf-file-on-any-android-device) thread. I extended the `PdfViewerActivity` in order to present a PDF file. It works pretty nice.

Snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ExtendedPdfViewerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, pathToPdfDocument);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Does it use MuPDF? I mean, is it part of Android (is there the source for it?) or does it use an external library?

Comment: According to their definition: `Native Android PDF Viewer based on MuPDF library`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then what are you exactly looking for?

Comment: "native support". Not a 3rd party library but a built-in functionality akin to MacOS PDFKit. Is MacOS really the only OS which supports PDF on its own?

Comment: I told you, on Android there is NO native support for opening PDF documents. I also provided a solution.