# Android API for Reading PDF

Tags: java, android, api, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF parsing library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android)
>   [How to read pdf in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application)

I have to make a application that would read a PDF document. I don't want to use external application to read PDF document.

is there an API for reading PDF that i can implement in my application? a API that will let me search and extract text from a PDF document.

Comment: Have you tried search before - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10299839/940096 And, if you wanna do some features like extract text and searching text and etc. You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11027745)

Comment: what you're trying to achieve is slightly outside the android philosophy. Android was buit on small re-usable blocks (heritage from it's linux base), so that you can focus on your actual app and not have to re-write existing stuff.

Comment: @Budius what do you mean by re-write existing stuff?

Answer (score -1):

You can use ITextPDf Tool Library Tool [Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html)

Or you can create a blank file and write on it as a byte code like this [Example](http://www.androidchennai.blogspot.in/2012/06/creating-and-writing-into-pdf-file.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i want a API that would Search and Extract text from a PDF Document.

Comment: I think there is no direct API for PDF in android.

Comment: @ChristianEricParan PDF document parsing in iText recently has evolved substantially; depending on your requirements you might, therefore, want to look at a current version of it (5.3.x). It comercially is also available in a special Android version.