# Android, read pdf files?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF parsing library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android)
>   [How to read pdf in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application)

I am developing an android application. I was able to open pdf files with adobe reader app in my application. But i want to "read" pdf file, I want to process the string that it contains.

Is there anyway to do that ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you want to extract text contained within the pdf?

Comment: Try iText: http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: @Thommy, itext looks like the solution, i am going try it and post the results.