# How to read pdf file in my Android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read pdf in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application)

My application will have a link for a pdf file. When user click on a link, pdf file should download to local storage if it is not already present and my application should open that pdf file in a pop-up window and that popup will have close button at top right corner of window. I don't want default/third party pdf reader to display my pdf file.

How I can implement this requirement in my application?

Comment: "How to read pdf file in my appliation" ... "I don't want a PDF reader" -- so, what _do_ you want? Rendering PDF is difficult, but you might fetch a GUI-less reader with a decent API and render only the controls yourself.

Comment: it seems you are posting this question like a client. not like a programer.whenever you post question, you should show your effort and your problem first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.Without third party you cant use it. If you force to use it, then images or some unicode

text type wont visible.So you want to go for OCR tool or use set of libraries and sdk for pdf.

Libraries and sdk.

This might help you

http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/

http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/