# Load the pdf file in app from assets

Tags: android, pdf

I have a PDF file stored in my assets. I want to load the PDF from my assets and read it in the app itself without using any 3rd party app to view.

I got the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application/10352422#10352422). It works fine when selecting files from sdcard.

Comment: have you considered copying the files from assets folder to SD Card?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647784/trying-to-open-pdf-file-from-assets-folder-using-fileprovider-but-it-gives-filen?answertab=active#tab-top "this will help you")!
one

Answer (score 2):

Following snippet might help you accessing files from `asset` folder and then open it:

```
private void ReadFromAssets()
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "file.pdf");
    try
    {
        in = assetManager.open("file.pdf");
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/file.pdf"),
            "application/pdf");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and `copyFile` method is as follows:

```
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For that purpose you'll have to use an ecternal library. It's explained quite well in the link below:
    [Render a PDF file using Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes yes i had seen that i am using PDFViewer lib but thys have not explained how toimplement, can you please help me on that

Comment: project on GitHib explains this. If you have not found the link on the mentioned link, use thsi direct link. https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Comment: No i meant to say that i am able to display the pdf from sdcard using PDFViewer lib but using the same lib to how read files from assests?

Comment: have a look at the ans I gave you earlier...there file is being brought from assets...

Comment: carry on to Library part when it comes to opening it.

Comment: yes i have done that also but its not showing the data properly, it shows blank screen

Comment: Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated and not a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you can open it using a webview

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourpdf.pdf");
```

Hope it works.

Ooops just now I checked, the pdf cannot be loaded in the web view
Sorry

Comment: No buddy its an expensive approach and also it takes some time to load  which the user cant wait