# How can I display PDF in android application(able to pinch that pdf ,clarity &fastrendering)

Tags: java, android

How can I display PDF in android application(able pinch taht pdf , clarity & fast rendering)

Comment: Possible to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583095/pdf-viewer-api-on-android/14583151#14583151

Answer (score 0):

You can see the project at http://apv.googlecode.com/ which uses MuPDF library. You can integrating with your android app.

Screen shots - http://www.aopensource.com/index.php?more=3

Other resources -

http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-pdf-reader-open-source-code.html