# how to load pdf file in a webview from assets folder

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I ahve a webview in my layout screen. I need to display a PDF file in that webview from my assets folder. I tried below code. While running app displays zoom in and out controls with a blank page(our PDF file is kind of large.is it due to that?).

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) //required for running javascript on android 4.1 or later
    {
    settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.pdf");
```

I dont want to use external apps to read my PDF. is it possible?then how?

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered already . For the details refer the following links.
[How to read pdf in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application/10352422#10352422).
One more is 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application/10352422#10352422](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application/10352422#10352422)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pdf.js from Mozilla to display a PDF in a webview inside an Android application.

Here is the solution...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21383356/2260073

Answer (score -1):

After searching a lot about this i came up with my own kind of solution

I used this website to convert my PDF to DOCX and then DOCX to HTML using online converters and then used the following code to load the HTML in my Webview.

```
String htmlString = "<p>YOUR HTML CODE</p>";


webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps!