# Android- Get text from PDF

Tags: android, pdf

I want to read text from a PDF file present in SD card.How can we get text from a PDF file which is stored in sd card?

I tried like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private String line = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);

        final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            private String[] arr;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                // Get the text file

                File file = new File(sdcard, "test.pdf");

                // ob.pathh
                // Read text from file

                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new                            FileReader(file));

                    // int i=0;
                    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        lines.add(line);
                        // arr[i]=line;
                        // i++;
                        text.append(line);
                        text.append('\n');
                    }
                    for (String string : lines) {
                        tts.speak(string, TextToSpeech.SUCCESS, null);
                    }
                    arr = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
                    System.out.println(arr.length);
                    text1.setText(text);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                // speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }

}
```

Note: It's working fine if the file is text file (test.txt) but not working for pdf (test.pdf)

But here the text is not getting from PDF as it is, it's getting like byte code. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PDF file format is not plain text. You'll need a parser library like [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to extract texts from the file.

Comment: Can I use PDF box in android platform??

Comment: Hello @ShylendraMadda, Hope you doing well! Act i'm also facing the same prob. I'm unable to extract the text from pdf. Plz help me..

Comment: @Namrata you check this answer it's worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887336/2462531

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have got the solution with iText.

Gradle,

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

Java,

```
  try {
            String parsedText="";
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(yourPdfPath);
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
                parsedText   = parsedText+PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i+1).trim()+"\n"; //Extracting the content from the different pages
            }
            System.out.println(parsedText);
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: what is the path format here?
I have used 
`/storage/emulated/0/Download/abc.pdf`
but it is giving error

Comment: What error you are getting? Have you added storage permission?

Comment: yeah I got the solution, there was permission error

Comment: is this free?or you have to pay?

Comment: It's free. No payment required.

Comment: I am passing this path but getting no data in return: /document/9016-4EF8:New Folder/nuts_bolts_blockchain.pdf

Comment: @Sahil use a file chooser to allocate file location.

Comment: Hi guys! I'm receiving this error: `java.io.IOException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/sample.pdf not found as file or resource`, but I have sure the file is over there and the app has the right permissions. Any ideas what's wrong? My code is exactly as the answer

Comment: iText is open source but not necessarily free. You have to pay for a licence if you want to use it in a commercial app.

Comment: @dm707 Have you solved your issue? I am also facing the same problem. Could you help?

Comment: Is there any alternative? I got an email from itext for purchasing license. I have to remove itext in next version

Answer (score 2):

PDF format is not your normal text file.. You need to do a little more research on PDFs this is the best answer you'll get 
[How to read pdf in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application)

Comment: Finally I can able to show that PDF but How can I get text from that PDF?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda u gt the data from pdf ?