# How to extract text from pdf in android programatically

Tags: android, pdf, text, extract

I want to extract text from pdf file which is submitted by user using android programmatically.How its possible?

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application?answertab=votes#tab-top) to display the pdf file from SD card.

I tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763405/android-get-text-from-pdf/) to get text from text file can able to speak it out but not from pdf.

But the thing is how can I extract text from that PDF?

Comment: @matty357 Tried it but not exactly as per my requirement, Is there any other simple way to do this

Comment: I don't see how this could be done without some sort of library, this is a much simpler solution http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfandroid/Extract+Text+from+PDF+Document

Comment: Just realised it is not free though, sorry

Comment: Thank you but is there any other alternative or free trail versions?

Comment: Thanx for your response.. @alex