# Building an offline android app with data from pdf

Tags: android, pdf

I have data in the pdf format(Not in english). I want to load the data to my app and app will be offline. What are the elements i shall be using in android to make the app which is like reading data chapterwise? As the data i have is huge,how to load it offline from pdf? What is the efficient way?

This is reference link for the app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.winjit.hclite&hl=en

Comment: Do you want to display the pdf with your app? Or do you want to fetch information from the pdf to use it somehow ?

Comment: I want to fetch data from pdf and display it in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the text of a pdf is a hard task in android. You can check this other similar questions to this topic which all have no straight forward answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390742/simple-pdf-text-extraction-on-android), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776848/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-in-android-programatically), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763405/android-get-text-from-pdf).

If you cant workaround this there are commercial libarys out there which you can find pretty easy  with your search engine of choice (I don't want to promote them here).

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion. What kind of elements i should be using in android to make it look like reading chapter wise?

Comment: If you successfully read the text from a pdf you need a way to detect the end/start of a chapter. If your pdf for example has a index page you can use it to get the chapter headings -> search for this headings in your plain text and split by it.

Comment: But if it is possible I would avoid taking pdf as input for what you are planing to do. There is a reason why most of the book readers have another format than pdf

Comment: Okay did not have idea on this. What could be the best format to take input from other than pdf?

Comment: This is a absolute new question. I would take a look at the the formats the book readers use. I think your use case is pretty similar.

Comment: Ok thank u.. Please do post if u get any information. That would do a lot of help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126618/discussion-between-markb-and-varuni).