# How to open and read json formatted pdf path in android studio

Tags: android, json, pdf, url

I'm new to this Android platform, I'm going to write code for reading the JSON formatted pdf path and I need to open that pdf file in my android application.How do I code for the below problem?

The Url is like this: `url://xyx.com/talentsday_toppers/Writing`
JSON format is like this:

```
{"details"[
{"id":"3",
"talent_category":"Writing",
"date":"13\/06\/2017",
"pdf_path":".\/image\/talentsday_toppers\/Indian-States-and-Capitals-GK-in-PDF1.pdf"}]}
```

Comment: Try with **iTextPdf** library and try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887336/7806873

Comment: That will get to result in String and then use JSON parsing to get data.

Comment: @Nithi Patel In XML file I need to add anything???

Comment: Sorry you have url to read write, then I have to check this library will work or not.

Comment: @Nithi Patel, I'm reading the JSON like this: 
JSONObject jsonOject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonOject.getJSONArray("details");
                            JSONObject jsonOject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            PdfModel item = new PdfModel(jsonOject1.getString("pdf_path"));
listItem.add(item);
 adapter = new PdfAdapter(listItem,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @Nithi Patel, any other solution?? in the place of ImageView we can use Webview to open the pdf file

Comment: Your code is correct. It will get all in list.

Comment: @Nithi Patel, Then in Adapter class how we use imageView know like that we can use WebView,,,  It will be work or??

Comment: Like this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296125/7806873 , you can view pdf in WebView.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, Then how do I use getpdfUrl() in Adapter class??

Comment: @Nithin Patel, Like to getUrl of the Image we use         
                 Picasso.with(context)
                .load(imageModel.getImageUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);                                                                    Like how I can use??

Comment: If you have both pdfPath and ImagePath in data. Then you can set imagePath using Picasso and OnClick of that item move that item's pdfPath to new Activity with WebView.

Comment: @Nithi Patel, No acutely only I have pdf path. So in Adapter class, i need to implement OnclickListener button to get that URL from Model class??

Comment: Ok. then make RecyclerView item click and on that get URL as per position from Model list.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, In MainActivity I'm using "RecyclerView" and getting the "Json object" adding it into in "adapter". And in Model Class have one constructor() and getter(), And in adapter class, i used one layout(XML) file in that file have one LineraLayout and WebView. so in onBindViewHolder() method what i need to code??

Comment: Then make click event of RecyclerView by this link using: http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/ Or you can make click inside Adapter class.

Comment: @Nithi Patel, If I make click function to recyclerVew how can I get JSON formatted PdfPath??

Comment: @Nithin Patel, I need simple requirement like this: when I click the button it should open a pdf file, But the problem is I'm getting the path in JSON formatted.So for that, i need to code that I don't Know how do I?

Comment: You already have extracted and Put that in Models list right?. Now, get that like list.get(position) in OnClickListner of recycler.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, Ok I did that public String getPdfUrl() {
        return pdfUrl;
    } How can i use this function in Adapter class??

Comment: @Nithin Patel, list.get(position) means how do I? Can you clearly tell me where to I add that code or how do I code for that JSON format?

Comment: You already get padf path and store in Model, So just get that from Model.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, How do I get and where to place?? to show that file which View I have to those things I don't know??

Comment: Sorry Now find the RecyclerView list item click and how to get data in that click. Now office close time.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, Ok Thank You.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, I get the URL                                                                     
    final PdfModel pdfModel = listIteml.get(position);
    String url = pdfModel.getPdfUrl();                                                       But the proble is i'm not abel to see in my activity. webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);
        webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+url);                                                                           I wrote that in my Adapter class.

Comment: if you don't mind can you move next comments solutions to chat.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, Ok I will. How to I??

Comment: @Nithin Patel, I have only 19 reputations. How can I?

Comment: right leave it.

Comment: You don't have to write that in Adapter class. Write that coding in new class

Comment: Means in new Activity and from adapter class start that activity and pass that URL like putting in Intent.

Comment: And in new Activity get that value (getIntent(0.getStringExtra()...)  then try this link coding...https://stackoverflow.com/a/40626648/7806873

Comment: @Nithin Patel means in another activity need to add Webview there I can show my pdf file right??     I don't Know how to Interact with one activity to another through putExtra() and getExtara() method.

Comment: This way you can https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859509/7806873

Comment: @Nithin Patel, While calling new Activity from the Adapter class getting an error.

Comment: From where are you calling?

Comment: @Nithin Patel, After the onBindViewHolder() {........   }                                          Intent i = new Intent(PdfAdapter.this,WebViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Key",url);
        startActivity(i);

Comment: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i = new Intent(context,WebViewActivity.class);
            }
        });

Comment: You have to pass context in constructor of adapter class and then pass that context to `Intent(context,WebViewActivity.class);

Comment: @Nithin Patel, Ok I will check that and if I get any issue I will reach you, Thank You.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, That's not working. startActivity(i);  getting error.

Comment: what is error check in Android Monitor'--> Error spinner?

Comment: @Nithin Patel, It's not at all accepting startActibity() in adapter clas.

Comment: Paste code here..of startActivity So I will help you.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final PdfModel pdfModel = listIteml.get(position);

       url  = pdfModel.getPdfUrl();

        System.out.println("Url of the:"+url);


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(context,WebViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("web",url);
                 satrtActivity(i);



            }
        });

Comment: ok now what is error?

Comment: @Nithin Patel, I totally change the code, Now I'm not using Adapter class and Model Class, Using 2 Activities, MainActivity and SubActivity. In MainActivity used the only button when I click that it's going to another activity.

Comment: good do it and solve that.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, But the issue is the pdf file is not opening.                                  Requesting  URL:url://xyz.com/talentsday_toppers/Writing   But path getting the  URL is like this: url://xyz.com/images/talentsday_toppers/

Comment: I have send that how to view pdf again try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview/40626648#40626648

Comment: @Nithin Patel, Still pdf file is not opening.   Requesting URL is different and  response URL is different .

Comment: Why both are different? You have to just set pdf=pdfUrl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148033/discussion-between-nitin-patel-and-anusha-b).